# MySQL - Delete all duplicate rows found in a SELECT

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have used a few different queries to try and get this done but I can't seem to get it to work!

I want to delete 100,000 duplicate entires of codes in this table, each code is unique and so i need to leave the originals!

The 100,000 duplicates I can display by using:

```
delete from serialcodes group by code having count(*) > 1
```

I then tried deleting using:

```
DELETE FROM serialcodes WHERE serialcode_id IN (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT serialcode_id FROM serialcodes GROUP BY code HAVING ( COUNT(code) > 1 )
    ) AS p
)
```

This when wan in browser takes forever and times out, I tried via SSH and it ran but did nothing.

Can someone help?

EDIT: My Structure

```
serialcodes_id    code
1                 ABC123456
2                 ABC123456
3                 IJFH87878
4                 OIJD87898
```

I want to flag up that code 1 and 2 are the same and delete only ONE of them, throughout the table, my select statement highlights the 100,000 duplicates properly I just need to delete them!

Comment: can you please provide a sample of your table so that we can better understand which records you want to delete and which not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a unique Index, with IGNORE. It removes all duplicate rows:

ALTER IGNORE TABLE serialcodes ADD UNIQUE INDEX code (code);

Comment: I saw this solution however there is also a column for code type, and two rows may have the same actual code but different code types, this hasn't happened yet however in the future it may so code cannot be truly unique in the table

Comment: the you create a composite unique index with 2 fields ....ADD UNIQUE INDEX code (code_type,code);

Comment: Can I add this, it will drop the codes, and then remove it?

Comment: if will drop all duplicate records where the UNIQUE INDEX say is a duplicate, but you cant say wich record was deleted (first or second,...). Here is the MAnua : https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/alter-table/

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you :

```
DELETE FROM serialcodes WHERE serialcode_id NOT IN
 (SELECT serialcode_id FROM serialcodes GROUP BY code)
```

Comment: Will this leave one of the codes in there still or will it delete both duplicates?

Comment: Yes it would (sorry for the first comment - it was wrong)

Comment: Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'serialcodes' for update in FROM clause.

Comment: @KiwisTasteGood : it will delete only duplicate entries, i.e. the 2nd occurrence of code

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE s1 FROM
 serialcodes s1 JOIN serialcodes s2
 ON (s1.code = s2.code AND s1.`serialcodes_id` > s2.`serialcodes_id`)
```

This will delete rows from `serialcodes` with duplicate `code`. Rows with greater `serialcodes_id` will be deleted.